# Lightbox.options is not a function - lightbox plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

I am using this lightbox plugin,

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/

I have items on the page similar to the example:

```
<a href="images/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="my-image">Image #2</a>
<a href="images/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="my-image">Image #3</a>
<a href="images/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="my-image">Image #4</a>
```

it works fine, but I want to change some options, for that according to the documentation http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#options it should be

```
 lightbox.option({
      'resizeDuration': 200,
      'wrapAround': true
    })
```

however i am getting an error

```
lightbox.option is not a function
```

so, how to set the options I need ?

**edit:** the option snippet I have is **AFTER** the line where the lightbox js is loaded.

**edit2:** also the options snippet is inside document ready

**edit3:** lightbox is loaded and is **working** fine

Comment: without seeing the full context of where in the page you're setting the option, I can only guess that you're doing it BEFORE lightbox js is loaded

Comment: Show us full code with JS /Lightbox loading sequence

Comment: @JaromandaX, i updated the question, as i mentioned the lightbox options script becomes after the min js file

Comment: lol - I added an answer before I read the SECOND edit :p

Comment: What does `console.log(lightbox)` say?

Comment: BTW, there's no need to put `editN` before each update to the question.

Comment: You have to provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue or at least a link where this issue can be checked

Comment: @Barmar, there were questions i wanted to address from the comments, just wanted to show that i added afterwards after their comment, otherwise it would look like that they asked/mentioend a point smth, taht was already in the question.

Comment: Did some testing and this ought to work. Especially if the lightbox itself works, then the options (and `lightbox` and `lightbox.option`) should too.

Comment: @A.Wolff, good point

Comment: @Barmar, `console.log(lightbox)` gives this `<div id="lightbox" class="lightbox" style="display: none;">`

Comment: thanks everyone for trying to help, when trying to create some standalone code to be able to provide to others, I used the version with `2.8.1` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turned out it has something to do with the version, i was using version `2.7.1`, I tried with the version `2.8.1` and the error disappeared

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem using npm. I solved it like this.

```
import lightbox from 'lightbox2/dist/js/lightbox';

window.lightbox = lightbox;

 window.lightbox.option({
        disableScrolling: true,
        fadeDuration:200,
        //other
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the ID of that `<div id="lightbox">` to something else. Browsers automatically turn all IDs into global variables, and this is overwriting the global `lightbox` object.

Comment: the point is that there is no div with id `lightbox` in my code, it is being created by the lightbox.